# Is there a way to make this type family injective?

Tags: haskell, type-families

The following type family

```
type family ListVariadic (as :: [Type]) (b :: Type) = (f :: Type) where  
  ListVariadic (a ': as) b = a -> ListVariadic as b
  ListVariadic '[]       b = b
```

is visibly not injective, e.g. `ListVariadic '[] (a -> a) ~ ListVariadic '[a] a`.
However it is very convenient to have injectivity to help type inference along, and I don't intend to use `ListVariadic` with its second argument being a function type.
I have come up with two workarounds, both quite unsatisfactory:

**Option 1:** Pass around type families that witness a left inverse to ListVariadic (through type-classes).

```
type family Arguments (f :: Type) :: [Type] where
  Arguments (a -> b) = a ': Arguments b
  Arguments b        = '[]
type family Return (f :: Type) :: Type where
  Return (a -> b) = Return b
  Return b        = b

class    ( f ~ ListVariadic (Arguments f) (Return f) ) => VariadicIsInjective f where
instance ( f ~ ListVariadic (Arguments f) (Return f) ) => VariadicIsInjective f where
```

For me this eventually introduced too much complexity, having to thread these helper typeclasses throughout.

**Option 2.** Explicitly list all non-function types that one is going to be using, in the definition of the variadic type family:

```
type family ListVariadic (as :: [Type]) (b :: Type) = (f :: Type) | f -> as b where  
  ListVariadic (a ': as) b = a -> ListVariadic as b
  ListVariadic '[] ()     = ()
  ListVariadic '[] Bool   = Bool
  ListVariadic '[] Word   = Word 
  ListVariadic '[] Int    = Int 
  ListVariadic '[] Float  = Float
  ListVariadic '[] Double = Double
  ... ... ...
  ListVariadic '[] (a,b) = (a,b)
  ListVariadic '[] (a,b,c) = (a,b,c)
  ... ... ...
  ListVariadic '[] [a] = [a]
  ... ... ...
```

Then an injectivity annotation is possible and works as intended. It's obviously quite limited... and one still ends up with constraints of the form `a ~ ListVariadic '[] a` that need to be passed around.

---

I was hoping there to be a way of writing the `ListVariadic` type family (or something fulfilling the same purpose), indicating that its second argument is not a function, and allow an injectivity annotation.
I know I am doubly in trouble, because in the provided first definition of `ListVariadic`, the second equation has a bare type variable on the right hand side. That's generally not allowed when checking for injectivity... but perhaps there are some clever tricks using type synonyms that can work around this problem?

Comment: Type synonyms (sans type families) are resolved before injectivity is checked, so that's not something that could help here. Also, you're not "doubly in trouble". The reason why RHS can't be a bare type variable in the first place, as far as I understand, is exactly because allowing that would always lead to non-injectivity or type-safety violations (there is one exception and you probably know of it, it's not helpful here). What you apparently want is constrained type families (doi:10.1145/3110286). Those are, regrettably, not available in Haskell at the time of writing.